# I18n redis backend pluralization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rails-i18n

I switched my app translations form yml fails to redis backend.

What i have in my initializer:

```
TRANSLATION_STORE = Redis.new
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(TRANSLATION_STORE), I18n.backend)
```

When i switched to redis backend i lost pluralization support.

time_ago_in_words don't work as expected.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: do you have rails-i18n gem installed?